# Pass value of reference type to Dictionary.Add method

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, reference, pass-by-reference

So I have a quite large 2D jagged Array that I want to spilt up into smaller ones. After that I want to store those smaller 2D jagged Arrays in a Dictionary.

To do that I use the .Add method on the Dictionary. So now I add my smaller Arrays but it seams that I only add the reference of my variable that stores my smaller Arrays to the `Dictionary.Add` method, or at least that is my conclusion after 4 hours of starring at my screen, Debugging and 3 mental breakdowns.

So if I change my variable for my smaller Arrays, which I obviously do because I want to spilt it up into multifile pieces I also end up changing the value that I store in my Dictionary and I end up with a Dictionary that stores always the same value.

I also didn't find that bug because before I changed my code, I ran my variable for my smaller Arrays threw another function or at least that is what I think I did. But I cant replicate that for some reason. So what is the best way to go about this and pass a value instead of a reference type to my Dictionary.Add method? I found out about the ref keyword, but not about a counter part.

My Code:

(currentChunkArray is my Array for the smaller Arrays)
(ChunkData.FalloffMaps is my Dictionary)

```
float[][] currentChunkArray = new float[ChunkData.verticies + 2 * border][];

for (int i = 0; i < ChunkData.verticies + 2 * border; i++)
{
    currentChunkArray[i] = new float[ChunkData.verticies + 2 * border];
}
        
for (int y = 0; y < ChunkData.islandSize; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < ChunkData.islandSize; x++)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ChunkData.verticies + 2 * border; i++)
        {       
            float[] sourceArray = borderedIslandMap[i + y * ChunkData.verticies - y];
            int sourceIndex = x * ChunkData.verticies - x;
            float[] destinationArray = currentChunkArray[i];
            int destinationIndex = 0;
            int length = ChunkData.verticies + 2 * border;

            Array.Copy(sourceArray, sourceIndex, destinationArray, destinationIndex, length);
        }
            
        ChunkData.FalloffMaps.Add(new Vector2(y, x), currentChunkArray);
```

Comment: Yes, arrays are reference types, and so passing them to a method passes the reference. C# has always been this way. It's usually seen as a feature, rather than an issue to overcome or work around.

Comment: For now I just gave currentChunkArray each loop a new memory location by declaring it complety again using the "new" keyword but this doesnt seams like a clean way to do it.